# HLS video stream keeps refreshing whenever new .ts is added to the .m3u8 file (using HLS.js)

Tags: python, reactjs, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am converting a live RTSP stream to hls and displaying it on the browser. Here is the ffmpeg command -

```
    command_string ="ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -report \
    -loglevel debug \
    -rtsp_transport tcp \
    -re -i rtsp://username:password@192.168.12.43:554/stream1 \
    -vsync 0 \
    -vcodec copy \
    -movflags frag_keyframe \
    -f hls \
    -hls_time 4 \
    -hls_list_size 0 \
    -force_key_frames \"expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)\" \
    -hls_segment_type mpegts \
    -hls_segment_filename public\%d.ts \
    public\index.m3u8
```

I am running it in a python subprocess. The m3u8 file created is -

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:5.973744,
0.ts
#EXTINF:4.015867,
1.ts
#EXTINF:3.997500,
2.ts
#EXTINF:3.999844,
3.ts
#EXTINF:4.000000,
4.ts
#EXTINF:4.012889,
5.ts
```

Here is the HLS.js code for the browser -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

     <head>
      <! -- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script> -->
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1"></script>
      <!--
          manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
          user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
        -->
      <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
      <title>React App</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> -->
      <video id="video" controls autoplay></video>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
      if (Hls.isSupported()) {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
          console.log('video and hls.js are now bound together !');
        });
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
          console.log(
            'manifest loaded, found ' + data.levels.length + ' quality level'
          );
        });
        hls.loadSource('index.m3u8');
        // bind them together
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        // video.play()
      }
    </script>

</html>
```

When I kill the python subprocess and play the file back it plays perfectly. But if the subprocess is running and updating the index.m3u8 file the livestream refreshes the page whenever a new .ts is added to the .m3u8.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got it to work by creating a server to serve the index.m3u8 to my webpage instead of accessing it locally.